# Assigning values to DateTime field using the system date minus few days

Tags: datetime

A.EventDate BETWEEN SUBDATE(SYSDATE(), 5) AND SYSDATE().

I am afraid this logic is not working. I need to subtract today's date (system identified) minus 5 days and assign the date range to the event date field of table A. The event date is a DateTime type field.

Thank you.

Comment: What language are you using? Show your code please, and we can help.

Comment: This is MySQL. The above code is in the where clause eg. Where A.EventDate BETWEEN SUBDATE(SYSDATE(), 5) AND SYSDATE().

Comment: This is the logic of the code and I am stuck at the point where I cannot get the date range to be flexible. Thank you so much. Select * 
From B 
Where B.PK Not in (Select C.PK 
FROM C Inner Join A on A.Pk = C.FK
WHERE A.EventDate BETWEEN '12/12/16 12:00 am' AND '12/16/16 12:00 am')

Comment: Prathvi, your question is not too clear for me. I will write an answer, but I do not guarantee it will address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to subtract today's date (system identified) minus 5 days and
>   assign the date range to the event date field of table A.

Then you need to issue an `update`.

```
update A
set EventDate = SUBDATE(SYSDATE(), 5)
where A.Pk in (select Another.Pk from A Another WHERE Another.EventDate BETWEEN SUBDATE(SYSDATE(), 5) AND now())
```

This is a flexible `update`, but I am absolutely not sure I have addressed the correct problem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your inputs, but I don't intend to update the table. I just want to run the query for a flexible date range. I am not sure if that's possible. I want to run the query for a date range of 5 days starting from today's date but this needs to be automated